# Esconder um botão em HTML5 e CSS quando estiver em Smartphone

Tags: html5, css3, layout-responsivo, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Fiz uma aplicação Web responsiva, que quando chega no Checkout tem dois botões: Imprimir e Salvar.

Só que o usuário (cliente) no smartphone clica em imprimir, mesmo não tendo impressora.

Já tentei estender com o @media, mas não estou conseguindo.

Como posso esconder o botão "Imprimir" e deixar somente o botão "Salvar" quando o usuário estiver no Smatphone ou Tablet?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exibir Div Apenas em Versão Mobile](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117414/exibir-div-apenas-em-vers%c3%a3o-mobile)

Comment: Vou ver esta se resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está usando bootstrap4, você pode usar a classe `d-none` (significa display none)

Como esse conjunto de classes aceitam prefixos, você pode adicionar a classe `d-sm-block` para mudar para display block quando a tela for small ou superior.

No fim, ficaria assim:

```
<button class='d-none d-sm-block'>Imprimir</button>
```

Quando a tela for small, medium, large Ou extra large, voce vai ter um display block, normal.
Quando a tela for inferior a small, tipo extra small (Ou smartphone) o display vai ser none.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal pela ajuda. A solução do @Andrew Ribeiro funcionou perfeitamente no Bootstrap 4. Obrigado Andrew.